# Why getPostParameters doesn't work on symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a form in symfony 1.4 which are created for each competence. My forms was created with success. But when I try to save my form I can't. I go to see my action code and the function getPostParameters seem dosn't work. I use getParameterHolder to see what's wrong in my parameters but after I put the good value the getPostParameters function doesn't work.

This is what I get from getParameterHolder:

```
   sfParameterHolder Object
([parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [professionnal_competence] => Array
                (
                    [rayon_competence3] => 24
                    [rayon_competence9] => 22
                    [rayon_competence19] => 32
                )

            [module] => professionnal_subregion
            [action] => saveCompetenceRadius
        )

)
```

And my function:

```
public function executeSaveCompetenceRadius(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();

        $q = ProfessionnalCompetenceQuery::create()
            ->addSelect('pc.*')
            ->where('pc.professionnal_id= ?',  $user->getId());
        $res = $q->execute();

        $values = $request->getPostParameters(['professionnal_competence']);
        $test = $request->getParameterHolder();
        var_dump($values); print_r($values); print_r($request->getParameterHolder());
        exit;

        foreach ($res as $professionnalCompetence) {
            foreach ($values['professionnal_competence'] as $k => $val) {
                if ($k == 'rayon_competence' . $professionnalCompetence->getCompetenceId()) {
                    $professionnalCompetence->setRayonCompetence($val);
                    $professionnalCompetence->save();
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->renderComponent('professionnal_subregion', 'competenceRadius');
       // return "test";
        //return $this->renderPartial('professionnal_subregion/competenceradius');
    }
```

This is my form:

```
class ProfessionnalCompetenceRadiusForm extends BaseProfessionnalCompetenceForm {


  public function configure()
  {
     unset($this['rayon_competence']);

      $this->widgetSchema['rayon_competence'.$this->object->getCompetenceId()] = new sfWidgetFormSelectUISlider(array('max'=>50,'step'=>1));
      $this->widgetSchema->setHelp('rayon_competence'.$this->object->getCompetenceId(),'en kilomètres');
      $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('rayon_competence'.$this->object->getCompetenceId(),'rayon');
      $this->setValidator('rayon_competence'.$this->object->getCompetenceId(), new sfValidatorInteger(array('max'=>50)));

  }
}
```

Someone has an idea or can help me ?? Because I try lot of thing but without success. Thank in advance :).

Comment: Can you show us your form?

Comment: Yes I edit my message :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error hides in this line:

```
$values = $request->getPostParameters(['professionnal_competence']);
```

You're passing an array to a function that takes a string. Try removing the brackets around `'professionnal_competence'`.

EDIT: Scratch that. `getPostParameters` takes no parameters. `getPostParameter`, on the other hand, takes two - the first of which is the field name - a string. So, your code should be:

```
$values = $request->getPostParameter('professionnal_competence');
```

Comment: Thank you !!! I try your tips:

`$values = $request->getPostParameter('professionnal_competence');` 
But it doesn't work but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the form by POST? Try `var_dump`ing `$request->getMethod()`, `$request->getGetParameters()`, and `$request->getPostParameters()`.

Comment: Oh my god! Yes the method is GET! I succeed to get my parameter and save at the database! Than you so much !

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
$values = $request->getPostParameters(['professionnal_competence']);
```

The function `sfWebRequest::getPostParameters` doesn't actually take parameters.

You can either access this array with `[...]`, or use `getPostParameter`, which allows "safe" deep access:

```
$val = $request->getPostParameter('a[b]');
// basically the same as, but with error checks:
$val = $request->getPostParameters()['a']['b'];
```

Comment: Can you try `$values = $request->getPostParameter('professionnal_competence[rayon_competence3]');`?

Comment: I try but nothing the var_dump give me "null". 
Look: 
`<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/var/www/html/plugins/ppPart2ProSubregionPlugin/modules/professionnal_subregion/lib/Baseprofessionnal_subregionActions.class.php:56:</small><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>`